Rename the tag [abnormal-psychology] to [disorder]?
I think the name of the tag abnormal-psychology can be at least for some people offensive. The word "abnormal" have the negative connotation. The word "disorder" have also some negative connotation, but since this is scientific term, it would sound more neutral.

I'm not in favor of this personally (speaking as a community member and not as a ♦ moderator). I will elaborate with an answer later.

By the way, the downvotes on this question are expressing disagreement and are not saying that your idea is of poor quality or unclear, things work a little bit differently with respect to votes on Meta.

I wholeheartedly agree with your sentiment, and I believe many in the psychology community think that too, but that's the "official" name of the subdiscipline as well as the name that of several well-known academic journals on the subject use.
I think that we'll eventually see this name fade away in favor of something more appropriate, but for the time being it would be confusing to re-appropriate a related term that, while perhaps more objective, doesn't reflect the existing body of work in this area.

If anything the problem is that "abnormal" is seen as "bad" in popular eyes. The term is not inherently negative, but it is properly descriptive. It's the study of psychological effects outside of normal behavior, development etc. Whatever you call it will be considered offensive by someone

@BenBrocka Quite true.  That's almost an answer on to itself.

It's an appropriate term. The meaning of "norm" in medicine is not the same than in everyday words.

I strongly disagree. "Abnomal" is the medical term, like abnormal anatomy, or anything.
It's not judgemental. A doctor don't use terms to please or to offense his patient, or to judge. 
Medical and scientist terms are like they are. It's not here you can change them. It's important to use the proper terms, used in the medicine field, to stick to the scientist vocabulary, and not "politically correct" terms, because soon, everyone will use his own terms, and finding offense where it's simply neutral and descriptive, and soften the actual meaning.
Suggestion:
Read Geoges Canguilhem's book "Normal and pathological", this book is the one that explains the meaning of "norm" in the medical area,
knowing what "normal" means, you'll understand that "abnormal" doesn't mean the same as in the non medical speech of everyday, and is not negative like in everyday speech. Every doctors or psychologist should read it.
Everyone interested in this field needs to now what is a "norm" and a non-norm in medicine. Because we have to know the meaning of a word before discussing it. Exactly like in philosophy.
Science is really like philosophy, it has its own terms, and they generally doesn't have the same meaning than in everyday words.
If you was to use "abnormal" in everyday word, I would agree, it would be insulting. Be here, you have to not make the confusion between 2 words that doesn't mean the same.
